# Homework assignment using loops to count (Java)

Tags: java, oop, while-loop

The assignment is...

> Write a while loop that prints 1 to `userNum`, using the variable `i`.
>   Follow each number (even the last one) by a space. Assume `userNum` is
>   positive. Ex: `userNum = 4` prints: `1 2 3 4`

This is what I have:

```
  int userNum = 0;
  int i = 0;

  userNum = 4;     // Assume positive

  while (i < 4) {
     i = userNum - 1;
     System.out.print(userNum + " ");
  }

  System.out.println("");
```

I keep getting an infinite loop error. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to Java and still trying to figure it out.

Comment: `i` will always be `< 4` if you initially have `usernum = 4` and reassign `i = userNum - 1`, thus creating an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use i++

```
while (i < userNum) {
     i++;
     System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
while (i < 4) {
    i = userNum - 1;
    System.out.print(userNum + " ");
}
```

to something like (since you want `1` to `userNum`, or `4` in this case)

```
while (i < userNum) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", ++i); // <-- since you want to start at 1.
}
```

as is you reset `i` to the initial value minus 1 on every iteration (thus an infinite loop).

Comment: Thank you for this, I changed the code but now it is starting at 0 and counting up. The book I am working with wants it to start from 1 and count up to 4...

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is the way you are handling i. Please see code below.

```
int userNum = 0;
int i = 0;

userNum = 4;     // Assume positive

while (i < 4) {
   //i = userNum - 1; // this line will result in i equals 4 minus 1 which equal 3 infinitely
   i++; // this means after each iteration of the this line add 1 to i
   System.out.print(i + " ");
}

System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below, I believe this would resolve your issue.

```
    int i = 0;
    int userNum = 4;
    while (i < userNum) {
    i++; //keep incrementing i till its less than userNum
    System.out.print(i + " "); //keep printing i till its less than userNum
    }
//come out of the loop when i becomes greater than userNum
```

Answer (score 0):

you are decrements before print first i=0 condition check i < 4 is true then i=i-1 which is equal to -1 and print again i<4 again decrements i was -1 now -2 so that's why you are getting infinite loop

```
System.out.println(i + " "); 
i++;
```